# boto3 key error for S3 with correct key and algorithm

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-kms

I have the following module:

```
def get_details(N, bucket_path):

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    files = recent_N(str(N), bucket_path)
    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_path)

    for obj in bucket.objects.all():
        key = obj.key
        if key in files:
            body = obj.get(SSECustomerAlgorithm='AES256', SSECustomerKey='')['Body'].read()
            s3.Bucket('bucket_2').put_object(Key=key, Body=body)
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the GetObject operation: The encryption parameters are not applicable to this object.
```

Is there anything which I did wrong?

Boto Version: `boto3==1.4.4`

PS: Yes, the key is correct. I checked it multiple times.

Comment: Is the object encrypted? When posting questions like this, always include Boto3 version.

Comment: @helloV Added the version, thanks :)  I used SSE(kms) for uploading the object. So, not sure. I don't think the object is encrypted!